# calling external programs asynchronously in node.js

Tags: asynchronous

I have a a Perl program that uses threads to spawn multiple processes doing the same tasks. For example, the Perl program parses a set of files in a directory that are fixed length files and creates output in excel. The directory will have multiple such fixed length files. The Perl program calls 10 threads and parses the file in each of the 10 threads and creates the desired output.

My intention is to get away from the threads in Perl and was wondering if I could use the asynchronous nature of node.js programs to call - lets say 10 of these Perl programs on a set of 10 files and so on till all the files in the given directory are parsed.

Having researched node.js I understood that I could call external programs (the Perl program in this specific case) through node.js. However, I was not able to ascertain if these calls to external programs in node.js are asynchronous in nature. If they are, then I can potentially write a wrapper in node.js that calls the Perl program for oh - lets say in 10 iterations so that the 10 Perl programs run simultaneously (well, almost simultaneously I guess) and I can get rid of the threads in the Perl program.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html Looks like it uses events, which means it should be async.